# Tapping a button in RxSwift doesn't call Moya network request in the flatmap scope

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming

Tapping a button doesn't call a Moya network request in the Flatmap chain and return a Observable of the Moya network request.

- I have tried to change the type of `didButtonTapped` as BehaviorRelay or PublishRelay.
- I have tried to change the button binding to `asDriver`.

```
var didButtonTapped = PublishRelay<Void>()
```

### - buttonTappedBinding

```
private func buttonTappedBinding() {
  self.button.rx.tap
    .throttle(0.3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .bind(to: self.viewModel.didButtonTapped)
    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
}
```

### -- didButtonTappedCallback

```
  private func didButtonTappedCallback() {
    self.didButtonTapped
      .flatMap { [weak self] _  -> Observable<TestModel> in
        return self?.moyaNetworkRequest() ?? .empty()
      }
      .subscribe(onNext: { model in
        print("Test Model \(model)")
      })
      .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
  }
```

### - Moya Network Request

```
  private func moyaNetworkRequest() -> Observable<TestModel> {
    let provider = MoyaProvider<TestAPI>(plugins: [])

    return provider.rx.request(.testInfo())
      .filter(statusCode: 200)
      .map(TestModel.self)
      .asObservable()
  }
```

When the viewModel is initialized I add `didButtonTappedCallback` function to set the observer. Then if tapping the button is occurred, The observer should call the Moya network request and get the result as an observable. But it doesn't call the network API.

## Different Approach

```
  private func didButtonTappedCallback() {
    self.didButtonTapped
      .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
        let provider = MoyaProvider<TestAPI>(plugins: [])

        return provider.rx.request(.testInfo())
          .filter(statusCode: 200)
          .map(TestModel.self)
          .asObservable()
          .subscribe(onNext: model in 
            print("Test Model \(model)")   
          })
          .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
      })
      .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
  }
```

If I do like this, it calls the network API. But I don't know why I can't use `Flatmap` chain with it.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51055281/updating-moya-rxswift-breaking-my-network-calls/51055887#51055887) and the issue was happened by the position of Moya provider.

According to the link I repositioned Moya provider property to the class and then it works.